# Changes to HTML not happening

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am expecting to hide the child ".summary-thumbnail-event-date" element in a specific parent "#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1697649009477_55853" element.  This code works.

```
function myFunction(parent_elem_id, child_elem ) {
  const hasID = document.getElementById(parent_elem_id);
  if (hasID !== null) {
    console.error('ID div not found');
  }
  var hasSelector = hasID.querySelector('.' + child_elem);
  if (hasSelector !== null) {
    console.error('Class div not found');
  }
  if (hasSelector) {
  // Change hasSelector var Name
    var OldDiv = hasSelector
    // Creates new div
    var NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    NewDiv.className = child_elem;
    NewDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    // Adjust the visibility
    NewDiv.innerHTML = OldDiv.innerHTML;
    // InsertBefore
    OldDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(NewDiv, OldDiv);
    OldDiv.parentNode.removeChild(OldDiv);
    return NewDiv
    } else {
      console.error('Child div not found');
    }
  }
//
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  myFunction('block-yui_3_17_2_1_1697649009477_34199', 'summary-thumbnail-event-date');
  });

<div id='block-yui_3_17_2_1_1697649009477_34199'>
  <div class='summary-thumbnail-event-date'>
    <p>This is a block.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='block-yui_3_17_2_1_1699287411992_11273'>
  <div class='summary-thumbnail-event-date'>
    <p>Something to think about.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='block-yui_3_17_2_1_1697649009477_55853'>
  <div class='summary-thumbnail-event-date'>
    <p>This is the last block.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes, you could do this as well ... for the function.

```
function myFunction(x,y) {
var a = document.getElementById(x);
var b = a.querySelector('.'+y);
return b.style.visibility = "hidden";
};
```

The going concern I have is the code doesn't change the html in a hosted environment. I am using squarespace.com

Comment: Please, for everyone else's sake, use decent variable names that describe what they are. `e` tells me nothing. Save the minification to the minifiers.

Comment: I don't want a decoder ring to read code.

Comment: While this may be slightly jokey - Heretic and Rory are right. Using variables that aren't somewhat descriptive makes it difficult to help out, since we need to read a bunch of code and cross-reference what each variable is doing. For instance, instead of `x` and `y`, something like `parent_elem_id` and `child_elem` would make way more sense.

Comment: So, now the real question _The going concern I have is the code doesn't change the html in a hosted environment._ - why not? Are the classes different? What does the squarespace markup look like?

Comment: Not next time. [Now](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77504225/edit). Put all information in your question or it's likely to be closed.

Comment: Is the code updated in the rendered page? Hosted environments often employ aggressive caching. I've had to get on the phone with web hosts and demand that they disable third-party caching plugins so I can work on a site. Can you open the script file and see the current code?

Comment: Yes, I can see the scripts.  isherwood

Comment: Update the JS in the question, not in a comment. Click the "edit snippet" button and replace the stuff in the JS box.

Comment: Changed and added to question.  Found the little 'edit' button.  Bad UI design. Thanks for tip.  Perhaps you all can read better and help out.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, try debugging your code through DevTools. Observe how the element behaves when you make changes using the function.
See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3u2groOG-A)

The code appears correct, but I am uncertain about its functionality within the Squarespace service. And because of that you should debug your code by yourself.

But anyway, let's take a look at your example

```
function myFunction(parent_elem_id, child_elem ) {
  const hasID = document.getElementById(parent_elem_id);
  if (hasID !== null) {
    console.error('ID div not found');
  }
  var hasSelector = hasID.querySelector('.' + child_elem);
  if (hasSelector !== null) {
    console.error('Class div not found');
  }
  if (hasSelector) {
  // Change hasSelector var Name
    var OldDiv = hasSelector
    // Creates new div
    var NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    NewDiv.className = child_elem;
    NewDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    // Adjust the visibility
    NewDiv.innerHTML = OldDiv.innerHTML;
    // InsertBefore
    OldDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(NewDiv, OldDiv);
    OldDiv.parentNode.removeChild(OldDiv);
    return NewDiv
    } else {
      console.error('Child div not found');
    }
  }
```

You can streamline everything. Initially, define only one function argument; it's truly sufficient for your task

```js
function hideElement(selector) {}
```

You should pass the correct selector as an argument. Remember that transform string into selector not your function responsibility. Build correct selector out of it.

```js
hideElement('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1697649009477_34199.summary-thumbnail-event-date');
```

Furthermore, you can locate the element and verify its existence.

```js
function hideElement(selector) {
  const target = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (target) return;
}
```

Then you might change styles.

```js
function hideElement(selector) {
  const target = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (target) return;
  target.style.display = 'none';
  // target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Finally, check the functionality result on a page. However, a better approach would be to create a CSS class with hiding properties and switch it accordingly.

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```js
function toggleHiding(selector) {
  const target = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (target) return;
  target.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

The best way - build markup with clear and convinient classes.

```html
<div class="card" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1697649009477_34199">
  <div class="card-content summary-thumbnail-event-date">
    <p class="card-text">This is a block.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1697649009477_34199">
  <div class="card-content summary-thumbnail-event-date">
    <p class="card-text">Something to think about.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look now please.  Found the small edit button.  Thanks for your thoughts.